# Angular2: what is the best practice to decompose into module(s) a feature that contains both a directive and a service?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-directive, angular-services, ng-modules

I am planning to develop a feature in Angular2 to contribute to the community.

**The feature consists of one directive and one service.**

**I am wondering how I can best pack the feature into one module (or more modules).**

- The service **must be global**, so it has to be imported into the core module by the users - it cannot be imported inside lazy loaded modules
- The directive can be imported where the user needs to use it

To make it work, I have to create two distinct modules: one to contain the service, that should be imported and re-exported by the core module; and another to contain the directive, that can either be imported where the user needs it, or globally in the shared module

Now, I kind of don't like this configuration because I have to split my feature into two modules.

Users who know how Angular2 works should be able to set it up without problems, I know, but still I would prefer if it was possible to wrap everything inside ONE module? Which are the current best practices to achieve this?

Currently I don't see any different solution: because if I put service and directive in the same module, then when I need to import the directive in a component, the service will be contained in the same import; and if the component is lazy loaded this will create a second copy of the service for that component, which would be wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you considered using the `forRoot` pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the service in `.forRoot()` of your module and require it to be imported in AppModule with `MyModule.forRoot()` (like is is done for example with the Router module).

Add `forRoot` to your module

> ```
> static forRoot(config: UserServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
>   return {
>     ngModule: CoreModule,
>     providers: [
>       {provide: UserServiceConfig, useValue: config }
>     ]
>   };
> }
> ```

Also every module that wants to use the component needs to import the module with

> ```
> imports: [
>   BrowserModule,
>   ContactModule,
>   CoreModule.forRoot({userName: 'Miss Marple'}),
>   AppRoutingModule
> ],
> ```

For more details see https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#configure-core-services-with-coremoduleforroot